# Why is Chrome resuming paused streaming videos after audio input/source automatically switched?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bluetooth, youtube, facetime

I'm running macOS Mojave and, just recently, Chrome has started to resume any paused streaming videos that I have in tabs that are open whenever something occurs to cause an audio input/source switch, such as receiving a FaceTime call or disconnecting a Bluetooth headset.

This behavior occurs on paused Netflix, YouTube, and Vimeo videos.

This behavior does not occur for videos that are not paused (such as Vimeo videos that have loaded, but not played yet), and also does not occur when first connecting the Bluetooth headset, only when disconnecting.